# ember computed in input value from each loop

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-components, ember-controllers

i have a input element on ember, while the value is come from each condition

```
{{#each items as |item|}}
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Judul {{item.no}}</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9 input-group">
            {{input class="form-control" value=item.title placeholder="Tambah judul" type="text"}}
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <a class="btn btn-default remove_detail" type="button" onclick={{action 'decreaseTitle'}}><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
{{/each}}
```

i just wanna "watch" while the input in value=item.title has change from ember computed. how to do that ?

Comment: Could you explain better the question, I really don't get it. Anyway probably you should put brakets around item.title ==> {{item.title}}

Comment: What are you going to do after watching `item.title` change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/07051e6216f7bee28c874fe11b0d4531?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C) for an illustration of a computed property definition that is dependent on a property of an item within an array. You can check `application.js` controller.

```
Ember.computed('items.@each.title', function(){...})
```

does the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to watch something deep inside an array dynamically, it is better to wrap those logics using a component:

```
{{#each items as |item|}}
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Judul {{item.no}}</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9 input-group">
            {{my-input item=item}}
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <a class="btn btn-default remove_detail" type="button" onclick={{action 'decreaseTitle'}}><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
{{/each}}
```

here, `my-input` will be your component having those logics and in the component's .js file,

```
computedProperty: Ember.computed('item.title', {
  //your logics goes here...
};
```

and in the component's template file,

```
{{input class="form-control" value=item.title placeholder="Tambah judul" type="text"}}
```

and any other logics which has to be binded can be implemented within the component's scope itself

---

@rakwaht, `item.title` need not to be enclosed with braces as it is inside an another helper (input)